# No nohup logs on remote server

Tags: bash, ssh, nohup

I'm trying to start a proccess on remote server with ssh.
I need to log stdout on target server (not the local one)

Here is the script:

```
sshpass -p mypwd ssh root@myserver.com nohup java -jar /tmp/jenkins/myjar.jar > log.log 2>&1 &
```

Process starts fine, but logs are created on local server. Checked with

```
find . -name 'log.log'
```

I tried to wrap nohup command to double quotes

```
sshpass -p mypwd ssh root@myserver.com "nohup java -jar /tmp/jenkins/myjar.jar > log.log 2>&1 &"
```

Process starts fine, but no logs are present on both servers.

How can I make nohup send stdout to log file on remote server?

Comment: The last command should at least have created `log.log` file on the server, or have failed if creating the file was impossible. Are you sure you know the directory where the command run? Did you look in the right directory? What if you redirected to a file with absolute path?

Comment: @Kamil Maciorowski, I've scanned entire server (from root) & checked manually the home folder  and folder with jar.  No file

Answer (score 1):

The point is that **nohup** must go before sshpass command to log all the output; every command with no nohup goes like this: `nohup command` or `nohup command > output.log 2>&1`

Comment: I tried to use nohup sshpass -p mypwd ssh root@myserver.com java -jar /tmp/jenkins/myjar.jar > log.log 2>&1 & the result was the same.

Comment: What worked for me: sshpass -p mypwd ssh root@myserver.com "java -jar /tmp/jenkins/myjar.jar > log.log &" I'm wondering why

Comment: I should have worked to you; sometimes the redirection 2>&1 may cause interferences, if you type nohup shpass -p mypwd ssh root@myserver.com 'java -jar /tmp/jenkins/myjar.jar' > log.log it should redirect the output; the only point is that only the output would be redirected.